# Taking away part from Table 1 and showing parts of Table 2

Tags: mysql, teradata

I have a SQL problem, working i Teradata.
I have 2 tables, called Class, Table 1, and Grades, Table 2.
From Table 1 I want to extract a specific Group of students from a specific Class, Year 1 etc and show some additional data.
To the data from Table 1 I want to add the grades from a specific subject, but not all the students are taking this subject and for them I want to have a NULL result.

I know how to get the data with only the students that takes the Subject, but then I am missing the other students.

```
SELECT
a.Name
a.Age
b.Subject
b.grade

FROM  Table1 a                                 
LEFT JOIN Table2  b ON a.name=b.name

WHERE a.group in ('1')
AND b.subject in ('2')
;
```

Also, I know that Subject 1=English, 2=History, 3=Math, so I would like the numbers to be switched to the actual names.

Parts of the Data:

```
Table1                  Table2      
Group   Name    Age         Name    Subject Grade
1       Anna    12          Anna    1       A
1       Bengt   11          Anna    2       B
1       Cesar   12          Bengt   1       A
2       David   12          Bengt   2       A
2       Eric    13          Bengt   3       C
2       Filip   12          Cesar   1       C
3       Gustav  14          Cesar   3       C
3       Hugo    14          Cesar   4       B
3       Inga    14          Cesar   5       A
```

What I get:

```
Name    Age Subject Grade
Anna    12  2       B
Bengt   11  2       A
```

What I want:

```
Name    Age Subject Grade
Anna    12  History B
Bengt   11  History A
Cesar   12
```

Please, can anyone help me.

FINAL SQL

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT(a.Name)
    a.Age
    (CASE When b.scan_type_cd in ('2') then 'History' else NULL END) AS History,
    b.grade

    FROM  Table1 a                                 
    LEFT JOIN Table2  b ON a.name=b.name AND b.scan_type_cd in ('2')

    WHERE a.group in ('1')
    ;
```

Comment: There's a basic rule of thumb for outer joins: conditionas on the outer table should be placed in WHERE while conditions on the inner table should be placed in ON: `FROM  Table1 a                                 
LEFT JOIN Table2  b ON a.name=b.name
AND b.subject in ('2')
WHERE a.group in ('1')`
 See https://info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_16_00/SQL_Reference/B035-1146-160K/gea1472240815347.html#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a separate table called Subjects and then join on the Subject/ID. That way you can replace the numbers with names. Alternatively you can use `IF(b.subject = 1,'English',IF(b.subject = 2,'History',IF(b.subject = 3,'Science')))` but this isn't very suitable for lots of subjects.

The `WHERE` bit is your issue. You need to put it on the LEFT JOIN so your query would read something like this:

`ON a.name = b.name AND subject = 2`

Try that ...

By restricting on the JOIN you still return the other rows - the WHERE occurs after the join has happened hence why you are not seeing all the students.

Comment: The IF part I think will work since I am only interested in one subject at the time.

Remonig the Subject part from WHERE, then I get all the subject. And I am only interested in one how one subject is "affecting" the grades in the class at the time. Both students taking the subject and not taking the subject.

Comment: Ah - I think I can see the problem .. revising my answer

Answer (score 0):

your query is using IN but you don't need it. Fix the WHERE part as below and see if it works as expected:

```
SELECT
a.Name
a.Age
b.Subject
b.grade

FROM  Table1 a                                 
LEFT JOIN Table2  b ON a.name=b.name

WHERE a.group='1'
AND b.subject='2';
```

For the part about showing names instead of ids for the subject you have to introduce another join in the query

Comment: Thanks, but this is giving me the exact same result. I only get the students that is actually taking the Subject, but is missing the students not taking it, and I would like to show the whole class list.

Comment: Does not matter if it is Right or Left join, I still only get the once taking the subject.